# Subtract corresponding elements from 2 lists that both contain column matrices

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 lists

```
A= matrix([[ 9],
            [5],
            [7],
            [ 8]]), matrix([[2],
            [3],
            [7],
            [8])]

B = matrix([[ 3],
            [2],
            [1],
            [ 4]]), matrix([[2],
            [3],
            [2],
            [5])]
```

I want subtract the first matrix in the second list B from the first matrix in the first list A. To get the matrix

```
    matrix([[3],
            [3],
            [6],
            [4])
```

then the second from the second, and add these new matrices to a new list C.

I tried the code

```
 C=list()
    for j in A :
        for k in B: 
            C.append(j-k)
```

But it's not giving the correct answers . What are your suggestions?

Comment: Use a single for loop or list comprehension and `zip`.

Comment: I don't understand how one loop can do it. I still didn't get anywhere with this. :(

Comment: `[a-b for a, b in zip(A, B)]`

Comment: what are a and b?, let me clarify my intentions since the code doesn't seem to work

I have two lists: list A and list B, they are both filled with column vectors, I want to subtract the corresponding column vectors. I want to subtract the first column vector in B from the first column vector in A. I want to add this new column vector to a new list C. Then I want the code to subtract the second column vector from B from the second column vector from A and add this new column vector to C and so on. The code above shows the content of the list aka the vectors when I print (A) and print (B)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: ok the example is rather basic it doesn't help me . I don't understand how to apply it to my problem

Comment: Ok I resolved the problem using numpy :D thanks anyway